# Adding an asterisk BEFORE the colon on a required form label

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a form which has some required fields, and I want to add an asterisk on the labels for the required input fields. The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to make it so that the asterisk comes BEFORE the colon, and not after. It needs to look like this:
[image: How the label should look]

But right now it looks like this:

[image: How the label looks now]

This is my html:

```
<li class="form-row">
  <label class="required" for="first-name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="John" required/>
</li>
```

And my CSS for how I originally tried to solve this issue:

```
.required:after {
   content: "*"
 }
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a red asterisk to required fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550837/adding-a-red-asterisk-to-required-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can modify the HTML, you can just insert a `<span>` tag around the colon, and then use the target `.required span:before`:

```css
.required span:before {
  content: "*"
}
```

```html
<li class="form-row">
  <label class="required" for="first-name">First Name<span>:</span></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="John" required/>
</li>
```

Comment: So simple, how did I not think of that. But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since this is already somewhat style-abuse to produce content, why not make the ":" part of the style too?

```css
label::after {
  content: ":";
}

label.required::after {
  content: "*:";
}
```

```html
<label class="required" for="first-name">First Name</label><br>
<label  for="first-name">Last Name</label>
```

Also, note that `::after` is supposed to have *two* colons.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.firstName span:before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class='firstName' for='first-name'>
   First Name<span>:</span>
</label>

<input type='text' placeholder='required' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```css
.required:after {
  content: "* :";
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  margin-left:-4px;
}
```

```html
<label class="required" for="first-name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="John" required/>
```